# Highcharts: series gaps for "columnrange"

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a columnrange chart with several series. Because each series has a different number of points, it renders not equal gaps between series - see http://jsfiddle.net/czQ9e/

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            groupPadding: 0
        },
        columnrange: {
            grouping: true,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.y + '°C';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to get equal gaps across all series, even if some groups have "missing" series.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In general, Highcharts will reserve space for each columns, not only existing. You can avoid this by splitting series into two each. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/czQ9e/1/

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Temperatures',
        id: 'temps',
        color: 'blue',
        data: [
            [-9.7, 9.4],
            [-8.7, 6.5],
            [-3.5, 9.4],
            [-1.4, 19.9],
            [0.0, 22.6],
            [2.9, 29.5]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Temperatures',
        linkedTo: 'temps',
        grouping: false,
        color: 'blue',
        data: [
            [6, 9.2, 30.7],
            [7, 7.3, 26.5],
            [8, 4.4, 18.0],
            [9, -3.1, 11.4],
            [10, -5.2, 10.4],
            [11, -13.5, 9.8]
        ]
    }, {
       name: 'Trend',
        data: [
            [-19.7, 3.4],
            [-18.7, 6.5],
            [-3.5, 6.4],
            [-1.4, 9.9],
            [-9.2, 12.4],
            [-3.5, 19.8]
        ]
    }]
```

Comment: Thanks, but bars with different widths look not good also. maybe someone could suggest a fix to run after the chart is rendered. I guess it should be possible to make widths of non-existing series zero.

Comment: I don't think so. Anyway, play around in my solution with `pointPadding`, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/czQ9e/2/

Comment: If this won't resolve issue, attach screenshot what you expect to see. Maybe I misunderstood something :)

Comment: I am trying to achieve equal bar widths and equal gaps between bars - just to get a better looking chart. With your 1st solution, we get equal gaps but different bar widths. With my original code - opposite, i.e. equal widths but different gaps.

Comment: Wouldn't that kind of chart be harder to read for users..? In general, you need to use just one series for all bars.

Comment: The reason of using two series is to switch them on/off via legend. it is just a requirement to analyze either both or a single one.

Comment: There's no such magic option to make this working the way you want to, but you can try to achieve that by setting `grouping: false` for series. Then just play around with x-values to position points the way you want to.